# Change Text Colour Manim Community

Tags: manim

I have been trying out Manim Community. I am wondering if there is a way to change the text colour to black through out the whole program by calling `config`.

I can change the background colour using `config.background_color = WHITE`. I have tried searching online and trying random things (like `config.text_colour = BLACK`) to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac, I found the file at: `/users/<accountName>/library/python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/manim/svg/text_mobject.py`. On Windows, it was found to be here: `C:\Users\<accountName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\manim\mobject\svg\text_mobject.py` Then,  `text_mobject.py`, I did two/three things:

1. In line 68, there is this: `from ...utils.color import WHITE, Colors`. I added
   `from ...utils.color import BLACK, Colors` underneath. It gave me an error if I skipped this step.
2. I went to line 129 and changed `color=WHITE` to `color=BLACK`.
3. Only needed on Windows: Go to line 699 and `color: str = WHITE,` to         `color: str = BLACK,`
   Credit for helping me find this goes to olirwin in the comments.

**Note:** I am using Manim Community v0.4

Answer (score 3):

There is a `color` parameter for `Text`.

For example,

```py
from manim import *

class TextColor(Scene):
   def construct(self):
       self.add(Text('Hello',color=BLUE))
```

should give a blue colored text.

See the corresponding documentation: https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.svg.text_mobject.Text.html#manim.mobject.svg.text_mobject.Text

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants. It seems he wants to set up a default colour for all of his Texts, as to not have to rewrite the `color=...` parameter each time

Comment: I think that can't be done and it isn't always great to edit the source for this? Maybe make an [issue](https://github.com/manimcommunity/manim/issues)?

Comment: Thank you for your help! olirwin got what I meant, I found a solution by editing the source.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to open the `.../manim/mobject/svg/tex_mobject.py` and change the colour there :

```py
class TexMobject(SingleStringTexMobject):
    CONFIG = {
        "arg_separator": " ",
        "substrings_to_isolate": [],
        "tex_to_color_map": {},
        "color": YOUR_COLOUR,
    }
```

(credits to @Level-314 for [this solution](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/1145#issuecomment-647539479))

Of course this should also apply to `Text`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can't find the config files, I am using Manim Community.

Comment: I tried, but it unfortunately did not work.

Comment: What do you mean ? The default background color did not change ?

Comment: I meant I couldn't find the path. After some digging, I have found it though! I'll post it as an answer because there are a few steps. Thank you for all your help!!