# Globally or Locally change manim default font color for Tex and Text

Tags: manim

Manim Community v0.15.1

I am new to Manim.
I have been trying to change the font color of both Tex and Text objects without having to set the color for each Tex or Text object individually.

How do I change the font color for all Tex and Text objects within a scene or globally?

Here are some solutions that I believe I tried, but came up with nothing:

https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/1145

[Change Text Colour Manim Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896071/change-text-colour-manim-community)

I think this all has something to do with the following from Manim:
https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/troubleshooting.html?highlight=config#config

Here is a code example I have:

```
from manim import *
class My_made_Up_Scene_Name(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text_1 = Text("Text_1", font = "Arial", font_size = 50)
```

Where would I insert a scene-wide change of font color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`set_default` method](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.html?highlight=set_default#manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.set_default):

```py
def construct(self):
    Text.set_default(font="Arial", font_size=50)
    text_1 = Text("Hello world!")
```

Comment: That easy, eh? I've spent a few hours trying to find something like this. The hardest part is asking the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```py
class Example(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        Text.set_default(font = "Arial", font_size = 50)
        t = Text("Text_1 Hello World")
        t2 = Text("Foo, Bar").shift(DOWN)
        self.add(t, t2)
```

https://docs.manim.community/en/v0.15.1/reference/manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.html#manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.set_default

Comment: That easy, eh? I've spent a few hours trying to find something like this. The hardest part is asking the question. Thanks!